# set Attribute via href

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to set a variable (named as "o") in jsp in the body of  tag - how could I do it without scriplets?
I have wrote this piece of code but it is not working:

```
<a class="overfl" href="myServlet?action=request.setAttribute('o',i)"> ${values[i]} </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [JSTL Core c:set Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm) to set the attribute in any scope.

Sample code:

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

 <c:set var="salary" scope="request" value="${2000*2}"/>
```

---

`ServletRequest#setAttribute()` method doesn't return any value.

Get the value back in the same way as you are doing here `${values[i]}` 
or try with [JSTL Core c:out Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_out_tag.htm) to get the value back.

---

In your case simply pass the action values as query parameter as shown below:

```
<a class="overfl" href="myServlet?action=${i}"> ${values[i]} </a>
```

And get the value back at server side using

```
String action = servletRequest.getParameter("action");
```

Comment: I need to pass this value to myServlet class - not to other jsp

Comment: JSP is just like a Servlet. In the end JSP is converted to Servlet. Do in the same way as did for Servlet.

Comment: If you set the attribute in the request or session then you can easily get it back in both JSP and Servlet. Just set the attribute before forwarding the request to the JSP or Servlet.

Comment: in other words I need to make request.setAttribute('o',i) when I am clicking href. I have try- but I could not access the var "salary" from myServlet.java

Comment: OK you want to set the attribute on the click of hyperlink. I got it now.

Comment: Simply try with `<a class="overfl" href="myServlet?action=${i}"> ${values[i]} </a>` and get the value as `request.getParameter("action")` at server side. Here it is passed as query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If the varaible is not already defined in your request's attribute so call `<%request.setAttribute('o',i); %>` then if you want to  write it to the jsp output you have to to write   `<%request.getAttribute('o') %>` in the place where you want to add it's value like this  :

```
<%request.setAttribute('o',i); %>
<a class="overfl" href="myServlet?action=<%=request.getAttribute('o') %>"> ${values[i]} </a>
```

Comment: **how could I do it without scriplets**

Comment: Yes, without scriplets( . This is main a problem. I must pass this param to myServlet - when I click on this ref I am going to doGet function in myServlet. But I need to call request.setAttribute('o',i) before - to set this param